# MTLBuffer copy data to a specific buffer on host directly from the device

Tags: macos, metal, objective-c++

### Problem description

My program uses `MTLBuffer` to allocate some memory on the GPU and do computations with it. Then I need to copy the result to a specific place on the host. All solutions I found on the internet involve synchronizing the buffer firstly and then copying it to the place I need. Is there a way to copy data from `MTLBuffer` directly to the host buffer?

---

### Sample code

Current implementation:

```
void ComputeOnGPU(void* hostBuff, size_t buffSize)
{
    id<MTLBuffer> gpuBuff = [device newBufferWithLength: buffSize
                                    options: MTLResourceStorageModeManaged];
                                    
    //
    // Do stuff with the GPU buffer
    //

    id<MTLCommandQueue> commandQueue = [device newCommandQueue];
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];
    id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blitEncoder = [commandBuffer blitCommandEncoder];
    [blitEncoder synchronizeResource: gpuBuff];
    [blitEncoder endEncoding];
    [commandBuffer commit];
    [commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];

    std::memcpy(hostBuff, [gpuBuff contents], buffSize);

    [gpuBuff setPurgeableState: MTLPurgeableStateEmpty];
    [gpuBuff release];
}
```

What I'm looking for:

```
void ComputeOnGPU(void* hostBuff, size_t buffSize)
{
    id<MTLBuffer> gpuBuff = [device newBufferWithLength: buffSize
                                    options: MTLResourceStorageModeManaged];
                                    
    //
    // Do stuff with the GPU buffer
    //

    id<MTLCommandQueue> commandQueue = [device newCommandQueue];
    id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];
    id<MTLBlitCommandEncoder> blitEncoder = [commandBuffer blitCommandEncoder];

    // Is there something like that?
    [blitEncoder copyMemoryFromBuffer: gpuBuff
                 toHost: hostBuff];

    [blitEncoder endEncoding];
    [commandBuffer commit];
    [commandBuffer waitUntilCompleted];

    [gpuBuff setPurgeableState: MTLPurgeableStateEmpty];
    [gpuBuff release];
}
```

---

### Additional info

1. The size of the buffer transferred to the CPU is more than **4KB**.
2. `hostBuff` is a generic buffer. It comes from the outside, so I can't be sure that it was allocated with `mmap()`.

Comment: Is it necessary for you to use `MTLResourceStorageModeManaged` storage mode option for gpuBuff?

Comment: @HamidYusifli, In my current implementation - yes. If I don't need a shared pointer on the host to copy data from the buffer, I'd better use `MTLResourceStorageModePrivate`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answering your direct question: there's no way to copy `MTLBuffer` into a host pointer. I think the reason comes down to how virtual memory is mapped for CPU and GPU. And even if there was one, it would be identical to how managed buffers work, because the command you encode into a command encoder is executed on GPU timeline, which means even after calling that command method, you wouldn't see the result in the host pointer unless you end the encoding on a command encoder and then `commit` the command buffer and then wait for it to complete. There is however a method for copying between two `MTLBuffer`s: `-[MTLBlitCommandEncoder copyFromBuffer:sourceOffset:toBuffer:destinationOffset:size:]`.

But if you are using managed buffers, there's another way to do it. You can just call `-[MTLBlitCommandEncoder synchronizeResource:]` to make the changed made on GPU timeline visible and read the contents of it through `-[MTLBuffer contents]`.

Also, if you are always reading it back on the CPU and the amount of data is relatively small, you might just as well be using shared storage mode.

There are two articles that go more in depth on chosing a storage mode: [Choosing a Resource Storage Mode in iOS and tvOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/setting_resource_storage_modes/choosing_a_resource_storage_mode_in_ios_and_tvos?language=objc)
 and [Choosing a Resource Storage Mode in macOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/setting_resource_storage_modes/choosing_a_resource_storage_mode_in_macos?language=objc)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The buffer size is about 80 MB in most cases, so I should not use shared mode here.
I see no problem waiting for the command to finish executing. The problem I'm trying to solve is to avoid redundant copying operations. Currently, I copy from VRAM to RAM (synchronize) and copy from one place in RAM to another one (memcpy). I don't really want to `memcpy` here as logically it should be possible to copy directly to a place I need. AFAIK, it is possible with CUDA.

Comment: Well, actually I think you can use `-[MTLDevice newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:length:options:deallocator:]` to "share" a piece of virtual memory without copying it but still use it as "host buffer".

Comment: Be careful to read documentation though, you can't share just any piece of memory, it has to be aligned to page boundary and allocated by something like `vm_allocate`

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use `newBufferWithBytesNoCopy` here because I continue to use the host buffer after releasing the MTLBuffer.

Comment: But wait... `deallocator` is called for which buffer: RAM, VRAM or both? They don't mention it in the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtldevice/1433382-newbufferwithbytesnocopy?language=objc

Comment: You can use the version without `deallocator` or just not do anything in the block. Deallocator is called for the memory pointer you passed to the constructor, so host memory, when `MTLBuffer` goes out of scope. Driver should clean up VRAM for you.